# Why do we use wool for insulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, everyday-life, material-science

I'm really struggling to understand the science behind wool, and why it's a good insulator. I'm doing an investigation about heat transfer, and the topic I chose is insulators.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778). Results are immediately available  for the google search "why is wool a good insulator?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best insulation is air, actually it must be trapped air (not allowed to convect).  Wool traps the air, similar to fibreglass or other home insulators.

Answer (score 1):

Wool is a good insulator as it traps air in it and prevents it to flow out carrying heat with it and thus prevents lowering temperature of body